# Entering a binary in DynamoDB from a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to enter values into DynamoDB from a JSON string and one of those values is a binary. For example, binaryString = 'AAAcd'. I want 'AAAcd' to be the binary in the DynamoDB entry, but when I convert the string to a binary and put it into an item, the value has been changed due to the encoding. For example, the item in DynamoDB will be 'Qha=e' How can I get the binary value in DynamoDB to be 'AAAcd'?

```
    String binary = "AAAcd";
    byte[] bytes = binary.getBytes();
    Item item = new Item();
    item.withBinary("binary_col", bytes);
```

With the above, the value under "binary_col" is not "AAAcd", but "Qha=e".

Comment: where are you seeing the value as "Qha=e". Did you get the data from database using Java API and printed in console? I have tried it and it is working fine for me. Also, you should see the datatype as "B" in DynamoDB if you have defined it correctly.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? May I request you to accept my answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data as string as below and check the result. You should see the value as "AAAcd".

**Short Answer:-**

```
String binaryDataAsString = new String (item.getBinary("binary_col"));              
System.out.println("Binary data as string ====================>" + binaryDataAsString);
```

**Just for your reference:-**

```
public Boolean getAutoTableDataWithoutMapper(String autoId) {

    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);

    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("autotable");

    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = null;

    QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();

    querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("autoID = :val1").withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":val1", autoId));
    items = table.query(querySpec);

    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item itemData = iterator.next();

        System.out.println("Json data ====================>" + itemData.toJSONPretty());
        System.out.println("Binary data ====================>" + itemData.getBinary("binaryData"));

        String binaryDataAsString = new String(itemData.getBinary("binaryData"));

        System.out.println("Binary data as string ====================>" + binaryDataAsString);

    }

    return true;

}
```

**Output:-**
Please look at the "Binary data as string". The string is displayed correctly.

If you look at Json data, the value is displayed as mentioned in your question (i.e. "QUFBY2Q=").

```
Json data ====================>{
  "binaryData" : "QUFBY2Q=",
  "autoID" : "fge",
  "alexandriaID" : "122"
}
Binary data ====================>[B@3954d008
Binary data as string ====================>AAAcd
```